# function call from struct array

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I have a struct array that has the format:

```
struct command functions[] = {
    {"1", function1},
    {"2", function2},
    etc....
}
```

In a function run(char* function), I check if the parameter is equivalent to one of the strings stored in the struct array. If it is, I want to call the corresponding function. For example, if "1" is passed in, I call function1().

How would this be accomplished?

So far, I have

```
run(char* function) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_functions; i++) {
        if(*function == functions[i]) {
            return (*function)();
        }
    }
}
```

With the following errors:

```
error: invalid operands to binary == (have int and struct command)
error: called object *function is not a function
```

Comment: First of all show how the structure is defined.

Comment: you are going to need function pointers

Comment: I'm voting to close this because you're either lying about your code or you're lying about your error messages. Even if I fill in the blanks (which is your job, if you really want help), I get a different error message. Please produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ping me when you're ready...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with your code that seem to be causing an error, but unfortunately you haven't posted enough for me to completely fix them.

1. In the line `if(*function == function[i])` you are using `function[i]` when you probably want to be using `functions[i]` (with an "s")
2. In the same line, you are comparing a `char` against a `struct command`. You probably want to access the member of the struct that contains the string shown in your first code snippet.
3. You are (presumably) comparing a single character against a string. You should do this using `strcmp`.
4. You are not calling the function, you're calling a `char`, which just won't work.

At a guess, I think you want something like this:

```
run(char* function_name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_functions; i++) {
        struct_command function = functions[i];
        if(strcmp(function_name, function.name) == 0) {
            return function.exec();
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that the members in your `struct command` are named `name` and `exec`.